# SharePoint 2013 Content Organizer "Something went wrong" Error

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When uploading documents to a site with Content Organizer Rules, the document is routed to the correct library based on the metadata (site column) choices, but the system displays the "Something went wrong message" and a copy of the document stays in the Drop Off Library.

This only happens in one site collection. I can create a new site collection in the same web app and it all works using the same basic site columns (recreated in the new site collection) and same basic rules.

A new subsite in the broken site collection has the same issue.

I have deleted the site column (simple choice column) and recreated and have the same issue.

The errors that I am seeing in ULS for both the target document library and the Drop Off Library:

Target Library:
Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.

Application error when access /cotestsite/DropOffLibrary/Forms/EditForm.aspx, Error=Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only.